# How to uninstall VS Code and download it again

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code a month ago, and I recently got Unity but I did not get Vs Code for Unity. Now I want to uninstall it and install it to work with unity. But it saves my progress and directly loads in my files(It doesn't ask me what apps I am going to work with). Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code (vscode) doesn't have a separate version for Unity. It's just vscode with whatever configuration and extensions you have.

You have to select which editor you want to use in Unity's **preferences**, under **External Tools**.

The vscode **Autosave** function is turned on/off in vscode's **File** menu. When you modify a script and switch back to Unity, Unity will automatically recompile your scripts. This is good, normal behavior that you really shouldn't mess with. If you really understand the consequences and want to manually do an **Assets - Refresh** instead, the setting is in Preferences under (depending on your Unity version) **General - Auto Refresh** or **Asset Pipeline - Auto Refresh**. Disable this at your own peril.

Here are the [uninstallation instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall) if you really feel like you need to uninstall vscode, and there are also instructions to clearing its user data in that document.

Before you go that route and potentially still don't have a working setup, double-check that you've followed all relevant steps of [Microsoft's official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) to setting up vscode for use with Unity. There are some specific prerequisites to install, and some even require specific versions. There are also steps to take in Unity to tell Unity how to communicate with vscode, and steps to take in vscode to set things up.

Game development is a big and complex ecosystem. Don't let that stop you. Once it's set up, it's going to stay working.

If all of this is done and Intellisense doesn't work, you may occasionally need to open vscode's **command palette** and use **OmniSharp: Select Project** to switch to `Assembly-CSharp.csproj` if it doesn't automatically do that. There have been buggy Unity vscode package releases in the past that didn't set that correctly and you got the Editor version instead, which stopped Intellisense from working in the expected way.